# XPages - Dojo Accordion Container with Panes Autohieght

Tags: xpages, accordion

I have Dojo Accordion with Panes. Whatever i did, i couldn't  solve my problem. 
Accordion Pane's height is always the same as which Accordion Pane has maximum height.

I just want it to be high enough according to it's content. I mean automatically high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS to your XPage or theme:

```css
.dijitSelected .dijitAccordionContainer-child {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Dojo accordion's pane open with the correct height then.

---

Use theme "Bootstrap3.2.0" alternatively as accordeon works with this theme out of the box as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some investigations and in my opinion the issue could be solved by setting the CSS height property `height:auto !important;` on every `xe:basicContainerNode` BUT if you open/close an accordion pane then the height property will be overwritten :(

**XPage Source:**

```
<xe:accordion id="accordion1">
    <xe:this.treeNodes>
        <xe:basicContainerNode label="Container one">
            <xe:this.children>
                <xe:basicLeafNode submitValue="Container one, choice one" label="Choice one"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode submitValue="Container one, choice two" label="Choice two"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode submitValue="Container one, choice three" label="Choice three"></xe:basicLeafNode>
            </xe:this.children>
        </xe:basicContainerNode>
        <xe:basicContainerNode label="Container two" style="height:auto !important;">
            <xe:this.children>
                <xe:basicLeafNode submitValue="Container two, choice one" label="Choice one"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode submitValue="Container two, choice two" label="Choice two"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode submitValue="Container two, choice three" label="Choice three"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode submitValue="Container two, choice one" label="Choice one"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode submitValue="Container two, choice two" label="Choice two"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode submitValue="Container two, choice three" label="Choice three"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode submitValue="Container two, choice one" label="Choice one"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode submitValue="Container two, choice two" label="Choice two"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode submitValue="Container two, choice three" label="Choice three"></xe:basicLeafNode>
            </xe:this.children>
        </xe:basicContainerNode>
        <xe:basicContainerNode label="Container three">
            <xe:this.children>
                <xe:basicLeafNode submitValue="Container three, choice one" label="Choice one"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode submitValue="Container three, choice two" label="Choice two"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode submitValue="Container three, choice three" label="Choice three">
                </xe:basicLeafNode>
            </xe:this.children>
        </xe:basicContainerNode>
    </xe:this.treeNodes>
</xe:accordion>
```

**Firebug Screenshots:**

*After XPage is loaded:*

[image]

*After Pane Opened/Closed:*

[image]